# What is the best way to send Cocoa Touch Framework logs to remote server in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, logging, frameworks

I’m building Cocoa Touch Framework. I want to send my SDK logs to remote server. The approach I have applied is using below:

```
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+”,stderr);
```

The above code writing console logs in file, but the problem is this also writing system logs and will write app logs which is not useful for me. I need only my SDK logs and using this I’m not able to filter logs while writing in file.

Second way is wherever i have NSLog in my code, write into  file. But in this scenario I want to understand, how I will get exception messages if app crashes due to my SDK or will this continuous write and read operation makes app performance low.

So what is the best way to collect SDK logs and send it to server.